# How to get users from a existing database for identityServer4

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

i try to understand how i can bind users (email, password, firstname, lastname and os on) which are stored in an existing database (located: localhost:3306) into my identityserver4 project so that i can use these information to login a user or register a new user into that database?

I read some tutorials (specially http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) but i think this is always for db in the same project. my db isn´t in the same project.

In this context i read about asp.net-core Identity. but i don´t understand completely how that´s related.

Can someone tell me how can i bind a db in my project and what´s the role of identity with application User and so on?

thanks in advance

Comment: Implement some sort of user store, like the Teat one here but point it to your external DB. github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article is more relevant to your situation. The one you linked is for configuration data and not for user data:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html

In short, you want to access your user data through Asp.Net Core Identity. 
You need to:

- Make a user class containing the relevant fields as your database
- Create an EntityFramework DbContext class to map your database to your class
- Register your user class and dbcontext with aspnet core identity
- Tell IdentityServer to use AspNetIdentity

This is what your Startup ConfigureServices method might look like once implemented. Not pictured here is the DbContext and User classes you need to make.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<YourUserStoreDbContextHere>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

    services.AddIdentity<YourUserClassHere, YourRoleClassHereIfAny>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<YourUserStoreDbContextHere>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        // Other config here
        .AddAspNetIdentity<YourUserClassHere>();
}
```

Refer to the docs on AspNet Identity for details on configuring your user class and dbcontext: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity

Comment: Hi, you bring a lot of light into the dark. I have a question about the User class. Without identity i have a class users (like the name of the table) and in this class i defined all details for users (like email,street, gender..) If i use Identity i have a ApplicationUser class which inherits from IdentityUser. Is this the same class like users without Identity? Here i have to add special informations (like gender) which are not part of the IdentityUser? I hope you can understand what i mean.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement your own `UserStore` ([example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/295026919db5bec1b0c8f36fc89e8aeb4b5a0e3f/src/IdentityServer4/Test/TestUserStore.cs))

```
public async Task<TapkeyUser> ValidateCredentialsAsync(string username, string password)
{
      //This is pseudo-code implement your DB logic here
      if (database.query("select id from users where username = username and password = password") 
      {
           return new User(); //return User from Database here 
      } else {
           return null;
      }        
}
```

And use this in your `AccountController`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // use our custom UserStore here
 -------->  if (_users.ValidateCredentials(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                AuthenticationProperties props = null;
                // only set explicit expiration here if persistent. 
                // otherwise we reply upon expiration configured in cookie middleware.
                if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
                {
                    props = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                    };
                };

                // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
                var user = _users.FindByUsername(model.Username);
                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.Username, user.SubjectId, user.Username));
                await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, props);

                // make sure the returnUrl is still valid, and if yes - redirect back to authorize endpoint or a local page
                if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(model.ReturnUrl) || Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }

                return Redirect("~/");
            }

            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(model.Username, "invalid credentials"));

            ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
        }

        // something went wrong, show form with error
        var vm = await _account.BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model);
        return View(vm);
    }
```